# How do I make ngIf and ng-Template working

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

**Updating:
Thank you for all the help! My problem is solved! Seems that I use the same name for the template as the boolean name in the ts file. (and the ng-container one down below in the comment also works, thanks!)**

The case is I'm try to implement a notification popover, I want to show all the new notifications when there's any, and if there's no new notification, I want to show the empty message.

When I'm trying to use ngIf and ng-template to render these two, it always shows the empty one, even if emptyNotification is false.

Here's my code:
(html)

```
<div class="popup_over" *ngIf="!emptyNotification; else emptyNotification">
    //code
</div>
    
<ng-template #emptyNotification>
     //code 
</ng-template>
```

(ts)

```
...

  emptyNotification = false;

...
```

Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of emptyNotification ?  You using it as a boolean and a templete variable.

Comment: try changing the template name to something else.. `emptyNotification` is already being used as a variable... 

Something like `*ngIf="!emptyNotification; else _emptyNotification"`

and then  `<ng-template #_emptyNotification>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `<ng-container>`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!emptyNotification; then notification; else emptyNotification"></ng-container>

<ng-template #notification>
   // Code 
</ng-template>

<ng-template #emptyNotification>
   // Code
</ng-template>
```